# Add return type information in a fat arrow method

Tags: typescript

I searched in all possible ways but I can't figure out how to combine return type annotation and fat arrow syntax.

```js
class BasicCalculator{
    value:number;
    constructor(value:number=0){
        this.value=value;
    }
    add= (operand:number)=>{ // CAVEAT how to add return type???
        this.value+=operand;
        return this;
    }
    subtract= (operand:number)=>{
        this.value-=operand;
        return this;
    }
    multiply= (operand:number)=>{
        this.value*=operand;
        return this;
    }
    divide= (operand:number)=>{
        this.value/=operand;
        return this;
    }
}
```

I tried:

```js
add= (operand:number)=>number { ....
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you have to specify it on the left hand side of the `=` operator, sth like `add:(operand:number)=>number=...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write:

```
class BasicCalculator{
    value:number;
    constructor(value:number=0){
        this.value=value;
    }
    add = (operand:number):BasicCalculator =>{ 
        this.value+=operand;
        return this;
    }
    subtract= (operand:number)=>{
        this.value-=operand;
        return this;
    }
    multiply= (operand:number)=>{
        this.value*=operand;
        return this;
    }
    divide= (operand:number)=>{
        this.value/=operand;
        return this;
    }
}

let test = new BasicCalculator();
test.add(5);
```

But even if you don't write the return type for `add` function, TypeScript can infer the type in this situation. You can hover your mouse over the `add` function with CTRL in the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20BasicCalculator%7B%0A%09value%3Anumber%3B%0A%09constructor(value%3Anumber%3D0)%7B%0A%09%09this.value%3Dvalue%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09add%20%3D%20(operand%3Anumber)%3ABasicCalculator%20%3D%3E%7B%20%2F%2F%20CAVEAT%20how%20to%20add%20return%20type%3F%3F%3F%0A%09%09this.value%2B%3Doperand%3B%0A%09%09return%20this%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09subtract%3D%20(operand%3Anumber)%3D%3E%7B%0A%09%09this.value-%3Doperand%3B%0A%09%09return%20this%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09multiply%3D%20(operand%3Anumber)%3D%3E%7B%0A%09%09this.value*%3Doperand%3B%0A%09%09return%20this%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%09divide%3D%20(operand%3Anumber)%3D%3E%7B%0A%09%09this.value%2F%3Doperand%3B%0A%09%09return%20this%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20test%20%3D%20new%20BasicCalculator()%3B%0Atest.add(5)%3B).

Comment: Note that doing this breaks `super` inheritance (these are instance properties, not prototype methods) and forces the JavaScript VM to do extra work every time you construct an object of this type (all those assignments are statements that have to be executed every time the constructor is called). Better to learn and use the normal class method syntax and never do this.